# How can I serve an image from Google appengine image service with a side greater than 1600px?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Google Appengine images service to serve the uploaded images in my application. The case is that some of my images are screenshots and their length is greater than 1600px which it looks to be the limitation from the service when I am calling the serving url of the image concatenating =s2000 for example. Is there a way to serve my lengthy images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can set `=s0` to show the actual/original size image.

The docs don't really explain the `=s0` functionality too well, but they are pointing out that only numbers from [0-1600 are allowed](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview#Transforming_Images_from_the_Blobstore) in the `=sxx`.

Comment: This is what I did, I removed the explicit size sXX to 0 and everything seems to work flawlessly.